# is it safe to detach a thread and then let it go out of scope (and have it still running)?

Tags: c++, stdthread, detach

I have the following code, which I think works ok (forgive the silly/contrived example).

```
void run_thread()
{
    std::thread t([]{
        while(true)
        {
            // keep getting chars... to stop peoples eye's hurting : )
            char c = getchar();
        }
    });

    t.detach(); // Detach thread

    // thread goes out of scope here - but is it ok because its detached??
}

int main()
{
     run_thread();    

    // Wait here forever
    while (true) {;}
}
```

But after re-reading it I have a doubt about it. Thread t goes out of scope. I can't remember now if it is safe to do this after you have called detach()... I think it is, but as I say I have a nagging doubt. Can anyone confirm if this is good/bad practise?

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

Comment: [This `std::thread` destructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) might be useful.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, I did see that infact, but it says it is safe to destroy (does not tell me that its going to still run ok though). Even detach says: `Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits. After calling detach *this no longer owns any thread. ` But I just wanted to double-double sure : )

Comment: Off-topic, but a thread the literally runs forever could lead to some surprises for you https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#intro.progress-1

Comment: @rustyx ...lol sorry, ok I will   .. I knew I should have made a better example :o

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Thread t goes out of scope. I can't remember now if it is safe to do
>   this after you have called detach()

You `detach()` because you want to disassociate the actual running thread with the thread object. So after `}` `t` goes out of scope but the actual thread will keep on running until its instruction completes.

If it weren't for `detach()` `std::terminate` would have killed the thread at `}`

Comment: That's a really good point about std::terminate.. I had not thought of that : )

Answer (score 4):

`detach` basically releases the `std::thread` object instance which is the C++ "handle" to the actual OS thread, thereby making it impossible to `join` the thread later.

In most cases it's better to keep the `thread` instance around at some global scope so that you can `join` it later, for example before exiting `main`. That way you can ensure all threads finish before the main thread does.

For example:

```
std::thread t; // can be "empty"

void run_thread()
{
    t = std::thread([] {
        while(true) {
            // keep getting chars...
            char c = getchar();
        }
    });

}

int main()
{
     run_thread();    

    // Wait here
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(30s);

    // Before exiting wait for the thread to finish
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I usually only ever use this method - which was why I felt a bit uncomfortable with the detach method. But I think this answer adds to this question so +1 for that : )

Answer (score 1):

Such a usage is the *point* of detach.

Comment: ah pheww, thanks ... it is as I thought, but I just wanted to check with the pro's : ))

Comment: One still has to ensure the thread terminates before the program (main thread) does.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, good point, I have some thread-sync going on in my real code so I should be ok there : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok and safe in you code. But it does not have any sense. `main` function will utilize CPU and a thread function will get less CPU time. You can attach to forever thread and reach similar behaviour: `run_thread` will never exit, thus `main` will never exit.

```
void run_thread()
{
    std::thread t([]{
        while(true){/* also run forever */;}
    });

    // Wait here forever
    t.attach();
}

int main()
{
     run_thread();    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry that is due to my crappy example - I just had the example to show the "issue". But your point is noted : )